# how to disconnect phone from Zune software

Tags: zune

I'm getting a message that my phone is connected to the Zune software and I didn't connect my phone to any software as I don't own a PC. I'm very concerned, how can I disconnect my phone? I already reset my phone and that hasn't help. Please I can use your help

Comment: When do you get this message?

Comment: Also, what phone do you have?

Comment: I got the message November 8,2017 my phone is a Nokia Lumia 625. Is this Zune connected to my phone or my number?